# What is the recommended way on keeping a Database at REST these days via NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, encryption, api-design

I am just getting my head round better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers to encrypt
a sqlite db on the file system. I am also thinking about using Argon2 to
encrypt the relevant fields... As this will be sitting on the public domain.
I would appreciate any further guidance idea's and suggestions whether this
is a good start and what else i could do to secure it best i can for a web backend API.
I will also be using helmet (for CORS) and also web sessions as apparently JWT's
is not recommended. Here is an example of what my project looks like except replacing certain
bits like bcrypt with Argon2 and using Web Sessions instead of JWT's..:
https://medium.com/@rachealkuranchie/node-js-authentication-with-postgresql-sequelize-and-express-js-20ae773da4c9
Muchly appreciated, M.

Here is an example of what my project looks like except replacing certain
bits like bcrypt with Argon2 and using Web Sessions instead of JWT`s..:
https://medium.com/@rachealkuranchie/node-js-authentication-with-postgresql-sequelize-and-express-js-20ae773da4c9